# Swap a pointer between two objects

Tags: objective-c, c, pointers

I have three pointers, `*player1`, `*player2` and `*currentPlayer`.

The pointer `*currentPlayer` will always be pointing to either `*player1` or `*player2`.  To switch between the two, I've been doing the following:

```
if (currentPlayer == player1) {
        currentPlayer = player2;
}
else {
    currentPlayer = player1;
}
```

My question is, is there a simpler, more elegant way to swap between these two pointers?

Comment: `*player1` is not a pointer. `player1` is a pointer to the object `*player1`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, conceptually there's no simpler way.

Syntactically the ternary operator is a little shorter:

```
currentPlayer = currentPlayer == player1 ? player2 : player1;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use an array, this could work too:

```
currentPlayer = playerArray + (currentPlayer - playerArray ^ 1);
```